# Add entry ids to a session cookie/variable array on button click?

Tags: entries, session, cookies, saving

I'm looking for a way to add entry ID's to an array in either a session cookie or a session variable.

I've installed the LJ Cookies plugin (https://github.com/lewisjenkins/craft-lj-cookies) in the hope that it is possible with this, however I am stuck.

To give an idea of the user process for this:

- I have channel entries that are courses
- When a user goes to a course there will be a "Save this course" button
- When the user clicks the button it will add the ID of the course to a session variable/session cookie array
- These saved courses will then be available to the user if they click on a "View saved courses" button during their session
- Once their session is over, the cookie can be deleted

Any help on this will be very much appreciated.